# SAS Retain & Count Statements by Groups

Tags: count, sas, retain, retaincount

I'm a newbie to SAS and would like to have your help on my codes. I'm working on retain statement to count on the patients visits to different clinics within a month.

My original dataset is a long file (per person per visit).

| ID | VisitCode |
| --- | --- |
| 121 | 4 |
| 122 | 3 |
| 123 | 6 |
| 123 | 4 |
| 125 | 2 |
| 125 | 5 |
| 127 | 1 |
| 127 | 1 |
| 127 | 5 |
| 127 | 5 |

I'l like to have a wide file in the end that I can see the number of visits a patient to different clinics. Like this:

| ID | CtC1Visit | CtC2Visit | CtC3Visit | CtC4Visit | CtC5Visit | CtC6Visit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 122 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 123 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 125 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 127 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |

Here are my codes. Somehow the people with multiple records of clinic visits just went missing.

```
data L3; set L3; BY ID;
retain CtC1Visit CtC1Visit CtC2Visit CtC3Visit CtC4Visit CtC6Visit;
if first.id then do;
  CtC1Visit=0;
  CtC2Visit=0;
  CtC3Visit=0;
  CtC4Visit=0;
  CtC5Visit=0;
  CtC6Visit=0;
end;
if VisitCode=1 then CtC1Visit=CtC1Visit+1;
if VisitCode=2 then CtC2Visit=CtC2Visit+1;
if VisitCode=3 then CtC3Visit=CtC3Visit+1;
if VisitCode=4 then CtC4Visit=CtC4Visit+1;
if VisitCode=5 then CtC5Visit=CtC5Visit+1;
if VisitCode=6 then CtC6Visit=CtC6Visit+1;
if last.ID then output;
run;
```

Result of My Current Codes

| ID | CtC1Visit | CtC2Visit | CtC3Visit | CtC4Visit | CtC5Visit | CtC6Visit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 122 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 123 | . | . | . | . | . | . |
| 125 | . | . | . | . | . | . |
| 127 | . | . | . | . | . | . |

Comment: I don't think the code you've showed could create the results you showed.  Note there are some typos in the variables listed in the RETAIN statement.  Suggest you check your real code to see if there are similar typos.  Are there any warnings / errors in your log, or notes about missing values being calculated?  Finally, it's usually better and easier to leave data in the long format (one record per person-visit) rather than transpose into wide format (one record per person).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome and kudos to asking a clear question with desired result posted.

```
data have;
input ID VisitCode;
datalines;
121 4
122 3
123 6
123 4
125 2
125 5
127 1
127 1
127 5
127 5
;

data want;
   set have;
   by ID;
   array ct{*} CtVisitC1 - CtVisitC6 (6*0);
   if first.ID then call stdize('replace', 'mult=', 0, of ct[*], _N_);
   ct[VisitCode] + 1;
   if last.ID;
   drop VisitCode;
run;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping. I corrected one variable name on my retain statement and added "else" for each if statement after CtC1Visit=CtC1Visit+1. They finally worked. 

But I like your codes. They look more concise and clean. Thanks for offering a better solution! :)